# How to reverse a drupal patch on netbeans

Tags: version-control

Is there a way to reverse a patch on Netbeans?

Does simply copying the target file and repasting it will work?

Or can the patch affect mutliple modules and code?

Comment: A patch to core or a module? Is your code base under version control?

Comment: Usually a module, but core also. Info for both would be good. I  don't fully understand version control, so I guess not, only patch the file on my computer with local host

Comment: If you are not using version control for your site, then you will have to rely on the version history in Netbeans to revert a patch.

Comment: Version control explained: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control

Comment: It is easier to patch with Drush, is it possible and reversible that way?

Comment: Drush, git, Netbeans, etc. all use the same method of patching a file. You can use git or patch to reverse a patch if you still have the patch file.

Comment: In netbearns, I see a History >> Revert Deleted, is that how to do it?

Comment: I have never used the history reverting features of Netbeans, so I cannot say. I have only ever did it via command line

Answer (score 0):

Use patch to reverse

```
patch -p1 -R < path/to/patchfile
```

Use git to reverse

```
git apply -R path/to/patchfile
```